# Explain electrostatic potential and similar terms?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, potential, potential-energy

How would you explain

electrostatic potential,
electrostatic potential energy,
electrostatic potential difference, electrostatic potential gradient and  common potential

What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1):

- The *electrostatic potential energy* $U$ is the potential energy, in the sense of classical mechanics (i.e. the line integral of a force field $\mathbf F(\mathbf r)$) caused by an electrostatic field $\mathbf E(\mathbf r)$ acting on a charge $q$
- The *electrostatic potential* is the electrostatic potential energy per unit charge, i.e. $V=U/q$.
- The *electrostatic potential difference* is the difference in the electrostatic potential between two points.
- The *electrostatic potential gradient* is the gradient (in the sense of vector calculus) of the electrostatic potential.
- "common potential" is not a standard term.