# Electrical potential vs eletrical potential difference

Tags: electricity, voltage

I know this question was asked in some way or another, but my familiarity of concepts in electricity are very basic so I ask you to give an explanation using simple terms.

I'm learning about Voltage, and I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j3GrOKre__0&t=312s) which compares *Electrical potential difference* to *gravitational potential difference*. He explains it using the following example:

[image]

The point in which the ball stands in has a *gravitational potential*, and a point in the height of the table has a *gravtiational potential*. So we say that there's a *gravitational potential difference* between the two points. And so with electricity etc.

My question is: What is the difference between potential and potential difference? Where the ball stands now, at 2.0 meters, this point has a potential since this ball can fall to the height of 0.5 meters. So it seems to me that this height (1.5 meters) is embedded in the potential of the point, or we can say - of this *situation* - i.e., the 2.0 meters above the 0.5 meters. But no, we're assigning a *potential difference* between the two points. So what is the meaning of the potential of the 2.0 meters point of its own? And if it doesn't have a meaning of its own, why don't we call the difference a *potential*? This feels pretty circular. I can go on lol.

Please clarify with **simple terms**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Explain electrostatic potential and similar terms?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/563327/explain-electrostatic-potential-and-similar-terms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is: What is the difference between potential and potential
> difference?

The assignment of gravitational or electric potential at a point is arbitrary. The difference in potential (electrical or gravitational) is not.

> Where the ball stands now, at 2.0 meters, this point has a potential
> since this ball can fall to the height of 0.5 meters.

The gravitational potential (GP) is the gravitational potential energy (GPE) per unit mass. The nature of GP and GPE is that the zero point is arbitrary. But once the zero point is set every value of GP and GPE is measured with respect to that point.

So with respect to your ball and table, If the surface of the table is assigned a GP of zero, then the GP of the ball is $1.5g$ with respect to the table and its GPE is $1.5mg$ where $m$ is its mass.

On the other hand, if you assigned the GP at the surface of the floor as zero, then the GP of the ball with respect to the floor is $2g$ and its GPE with respect to the floor is $2mg$.

The change in the zero point does not affect the GP difference between any two points. For example, the GP difference between the location of the ball and the surface of the table remains $1.5g$ even if we change the zero point of GP.

It is important to note that whether or not the ball can actually fall to the floor (based on its location) is irrelevant. That's why it's called *potential* energy.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

We define potential of a system to be the potential difference between the required separation and infinite separation per unit mass (as we assume potential of system at infinite separation to be 0 since no gravitational interaction exists in that case)

Hence 2m and 0.5m above earth have different potentials with respect to earth and the potential difference between those two points we can quantify

Just as gravitational fields have potential electric fields have potential as well which are defined in a similar manner

Comment: So with electricity there's also a common reference like earth with gravitation?

Comment: @YoavKlein Earth is not a common reference, potential is defined for any mass and any charge